# Glassfish asadmin batch file not opening command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, glassfish

Hiii
I have two glassfish versions 3.1.1 and 4.0 installed on my machine.
When i click on glassfish 3.1.1/bin/asadmin window batch file ,it opens command prompt where i can create service and delete service and so on.

But when i click on glassfish 4.0/bin/asadmin ,command prompt blinks for a second and terminates.
Even i can not see the exception or error.

I think its due to 2 installations.Can someone suggest a solution so that instead of glassfish 3.1.1, i can open asadmin of glassfish 4.0.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two installations of Glassfish shouldn't cause problems.

I guess the `asadmin.bat` throws some error like "Java not found..." or similar when you try to start it.

To actually see this error before the window closes you have to start `asadmin.bat` via an already opened command prompt.

Click the Start button and type `cmd` in the search field, then start `cmd.exe`. In the command prompt, navigate to your `Glassfish\bin` folder and type `asadmin`. This should print an error message indicating the problem.

Comment: i tried this.It is saying "Exception in main thread UnsupportedClassVersionError  org/glassfish/admin/cli/AsAdminMain : Unsupported Major Minor Version 51.0"
How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

hiii i found the answer.

It was referring to default jdk.I made it to refer to jdk7 as said in this article.
and it worked fine.

Comment: You're missing the link of that article, can you please add it?