# Cannot create any JMS resource through Glassfish 4.1 web admin

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, jms

I have installed Glassfish 4 and tried to create some JMS resources for following a tutorial on learning JMS, but it is impossible. On web interface it always is appearing the text "java.lang.RuntimeException" and on the log console it shows the stack trace. This exception is thrown always I push the link "New..." on the page "JMS Destination Resources" or in the page of the connection factories. Here is the stack trace:

```
[#|2015-11-16T09:15:24.090+0100|INFO|glassfish 4.1|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=48;_ThreadName=admin-listener(5);_TimeMillis=1447661724090;_LevelValue=800;|

Exception Occurred :null|#]

[#|2015-11-16T09:15:24.097+0100|INFO|glassfish 4.1|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=48;_ThreadName=admin-listener(5);_TimeMillis=1447661724097;_LevelValue=800;|

Exception Occurred :null|#]

[#|2015-11-16T09:15:24.100+0100|SEVERE|glassfish 4.1|javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context|_ThreadID=48;_ThreadName=admin-listener(5);_TimeMillis=1447661724100;_LevelValue=1000;|
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException while attempting to process a 'beforeCreate' event for 'event166'.
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:422)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:394)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutComponent.beforeCreate(LayoutComponent.java:348)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutComponent.getChild(LayoutComponent.java:288)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.buildUIComponentTree(LayoutViewHandler.java:556)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.buildUIComponentTree(LayoutViewHandler.java:551)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.buildUIComponentTree(LayoutViewHandler.java:507)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.buildUIComponentTree(LayoutViewHandler.java:507)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.createView(LayoutViewHandler.java:255)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:256)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:123)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)

    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.sun.webui.jsf.util.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doChainInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:678)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor156.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.handler.Handler.invoke(Handler.java:442)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:420)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.handlers.UtilHandlers.mapPut(UtilHandlers.java:314)
    ... 51 more
|#]
```

I don't understand why the solution for this annoying bug is not registered on the Internet.
Can someone help me?

Comment: The solution is possibly Payara. Glassfish is an open source unsupported reference implementation, Payara while still free and open source actually regularly applies patches to the server software. There is little reason to install Glassfish itself anymore in my opinion. http://www.payara.co.uk/home .

Answer (score 5):

I was getting similar error while creating the JMS resource CF and Connection Queue/Topic. But below commands worked for me at command asadmin>

```
asadmin> create-jms-resource --host localhost --port 4848 --restype javax.jms.TopicConnectionFactory --property  Name=MyID jms/DurableTopicConnectionFactory
```

Command create-jms-resource executed successfully.

```
asadmin> create-jms-resource --host localhost --port 4848 --restype javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory --property  Name=MyQCF jms/QCF1
```

Command create-jms-resource executed successfully.

```
asadmin> create-jms-resource --host localhost --port 4848 --restype javax.jms.Topic --property Name=PhysicalTopic jms/MyTopic
```

**Deprecated syntax, instead use:**
`asadmin --host localhost --port 4848 create-jms-resource [options] ..`
Administered object jms/MyTopic created.
Command create-jms-resource executed successfully.

```
asadmin> create-jms-resource --host localhost --port 4848 --restype javax.jms.Queue --property Name=PhysicalQueue jms/MyQueue
```

Administered object jms/MyQueue created.

Note: You can safely ignore the Deprecated message. Just refresh the admin page resources and click "New" you will see the new resources.

hope this helps.

Comment: for later versions (payara 6 etc) swap javax for jakarta

Answer (score 4):

I am with the same problem here with JDBC Resources

**Workaround**

I was able to add resources using the `asadmin console` with the command `add-resources`

You can see the documentation here it uses a xml file: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4497/6nfv6jlim/index.html

I also tried the Glassfish 4.0 (not the 4.1.1) and all worked fine at the Web-Admin-GUI

**Explaining my case**

I am using Glassfish 4.1.1 (build 1) on a Darwin Kernel Version 14.4.0 with java version "1.8.0_40" (Java 8u66)

I tried to add a new JDBC resource at the admin-gui:
--> left menu --> server --> Resources --> combobox 'new' JDBC Resources

In fact the error occours in all options of this combobox. Also the same problem in the:
--> left menu --> Resources --> JDBC --> JDBC Resources (or  JDBC Connection Pools)

The Web GUI show "class java.lang.RuntimeException" and the log file says:

```
[2015-11-18T09:34:46.529-0200] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] 
[tid: _ThreadID=52 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1447846486529] [levelValue: 1000 [[java.lang.RuntimeException: 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException while attempting to process a 'beforeCreate' event for 'event157'.
        at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:422)
        at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:394)
        at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutComponent.beforeCreate(LayoutComponent.java:348)
....  [snip]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
....  [snip]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.jsftemplating.handlers.UtilHandlers.mapPut(UtilHandlers.java:314)
....  [snip]
```

Comment: @VictorStafusa This issue is [reported in github.com](https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/issues/21437) and apparently fixed in 5.0. Now that Glassfish is available though `git` and uses Maven it should be possible to build a development version and try it out even though this bug exhibits bad software quality and undermines trust in the Java EE reference implementation, the comments on the issue speak for themselves.

Answer (score 3):

This problem seems to have been solved in **Glassfish 4.1.2**, where it is possible to create new JMS resources using the web admin interface.

Comment: It's a pitty that they still offer 4.1.1 on the official netbeans download page :( 
What kind of software this is, if they release a broken application out to the world?

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to what [Porks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2090981/porks) [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33779868/4645883), if you specifically wanted to create a JMS resource, you can do so with the *create-jms-resource* command in asadmin.

`create-jms-resource --restype javax.jms.Queue --property Name=myQueue jms/MyQueue`

Also for those unsure about how to get at asadmin, there's a great answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26733953/4645883).

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19879-01/820-4332/create-jms-resource-1/index.html